# [SEO, Breadcrumbs]: Homepage Breadcrumb

Tags: seo, breadcrumbs

My question is simple, do I make Breadcrumb for Homepage or not?

Comment: You tagged this as "SEO", how are you hoping that breadcrumbs help with SEO?   At best they can get shown in search results instead of the URL and can slightly help link your site together.   Their SEO impact is extremely minimal at all.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your site structure.

However, on most sites, the homepage is a navigational hub for the rest of the site, so it makes sense to include the homepage at the head of the breadcrumb trail in this case.